# Detect right to left Language in Swift UITest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automated-tests, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to setup my UITests for localisation. Especially for **Arabic** and any other ***Right to Left (RTL)*** language.

In my case I have a `swipe(direction: SwipeDirection)` function that takes a value of `SwipeDirection` (`.up, .down, .left, .right`).

If I now want to delete let's say a cell, I'd just do `cell.swipe(.left)` and my `UITest` would delete the cell. Since the UI is flipped on *RTL languages* this has to change to `cell.swipe(.right)`.

I could not find any way of detecting the current device language, nor it's `UILayoutDirection`.

I've tried to check for it like this already:

```
let isLeftToRight = UIView.userInterfaceLayoutDirection(for: UIView().semanticContentAttribute) == .leftToRight
```

and also

```
let isLeftToRight = UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .leftToRight
```

But both of them always returning `true`, no matter the language.
Are there any other ways of checking for the current `UILayoutDirection` I am not aware of?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deprecation from Apple, this is now a valid solution in SwiftUI.
Declare the environment variable use:

```
@Environment(\.layoutDirection) private var layoutDirection: LayoutDirection
```

Then use the (private) var layoutDirection.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly that hard to find in the documentation

```
let locale = NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrent
let lang = locale.languageCode
let direction = NSLocale.characterDirection(forLanguage:lang!)
```

Comment: I am going to use that for now. I think I saw a WWDC video once about the locale and why you should not use it for that. Will look it up, maybe I'm wrong though. Thank you!